# Remove terminal titlebar on Gnome without compiz

Tags: command-line, compiz, 12.10, titlebar

I can't seem to run compiz on my rig for some reason. I've installed Gnome 3 and I am running Ubuntu 12.10.

I am pleased with the current setup but I would like to remove the titlebar from the Terminal and I see that if through compiz this can be achieved with much ease, but I can't seem to start compiz so if there's another way to do this could someone help?

I am interested to know of a general way to do this so I can later apply it to other applications I might want to run borderless.

For the terminal I am currently running the tmux terminal.

Answer (score 1):

First you'd want to create a new profile ibn your terminal with `File>New Profile`.

Under `Edit>Profile preferences` you can change the `title`.

Also read [this](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/02/how-to-make-your-terminal-background.html) and [this](http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/10/15-things-i-did-after-installing-new.html) that would help you personalize your ubuntu experience. Good luck with 12.10!

### Shortcut key for terminal, in case you already didn't know it:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>